# SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 52035

Tags: flutter, blockchain, ethereum, ganache

I am having a flutter app, and want to connect it with ganache for ether transfer. But when I connect it with my real device it has given me the following error.

`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 52035`

```
String rpcUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:7545";
  String wsUrl = "ws://127.0.0.1:7545/";

  sendEther() async {
    Web3Client client = Web3Client(rpcUrl, Client(), socketConnector: () {
      return IOWebSocketChannel.connect(wsUrl).cast<String>();
    });

    String privateKey =
        "cce548f8263f25d63613bb48b87391b9c83f07a3ede4a5f8380549f93c2ca05f";

    Credentials credentials =
        await client.credentialsFromPrivateKey(privateKey);

    EthereumAddress ownAddress = await credentials.extractAddress();
    EthereumAddress reciever =
        EthereumAddress.fromHex("0x3B0ae8eecdFe232b453Ea107B65B2B7FFE8d46B9");
    print("#################");
    print(ownAddress);

    client.sendTransaction(
        credentials,
        Transaction(
          from: ownAddress,
          to: reciever,
          value: EtherAmount.fromUnitAndValue(EtherUnit.ether, 1)
        ));
  }
```

This is my code to send ether to another account.

Ganache localhost RPC SERVER "HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545". How to work it on real device?

Comment: For localhost you have both device and computer requried to be in same network and you have to use ip address of pc on which this is hosted instead of 127.0.0.1